# Magento, on checkout change shipping cost for a specific brand

Tags: magento, checkout

Could someone tell me please, in which files do I have to change the code and what exactly to change.
Example: if the order contains a specific brand (for example Armani), the shipment of the order (no matter how many products) must be free.

What I need to know is this: 
1. in which files do the checkout functions exist?
2. how to check the brand of all ordered products?
3. How to make the sheeping free?

Thanks a lot in advance.
George

Answer (score 0):

George:

1. can not answer because not good at. the probably path may be 
   'app\code\core\Mage\Checkout' 
   and 
   'app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout'
2. how do you manage the brand ? In my case, I use the extension to manage the product brand.
3. have you tried the shopping cart rules?  It is in the backend -> Promotions -> Shopping Cart Price Rules

You will find it more easier if you using product attribute to manage the brand and use the shopping cart rules to achieve your goal.